# PHP Image Upload Is Not Uploading Image to target directory

Tags: php, image, upload, photo

#### Problem:

I have created a **upload.php** file, which contains a HTML form and the PHP code needed to upload images and I use XAMPP localhost:

```
htdocs/web2/assets/upload.php
```

I want to upload images to the folder `upload` in the same directory:

```
htdocs/web2/assets/uploads/
```

#### Script:

```
    <?php 

        <form action="?" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   

            <!--wrap input button as around pre-existing image -->   
            <?php
                echo '<label class="profile_gallery_image_in"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="form.submit()"/><p class="label"></p><img class="myImg" src='.$image.' height="100%" width="100%" /></label>';
            ?>

        </form>

    <!-- Commence Photo Upload -->

    <?php
        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

The form is set to auto-submit upon input type change. This appears to be working fine and the form is submitting.

However, I get no actual image uploaded and no error at all.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Whats the permission of your folder? does php have rights to write to the folder?

Comment: @TobiasHH how do I find out how to set/amend folder privileges?

Comment: echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($target_dir)), -4);

Comment: Didn't you forget move_uploaded_file ?

Comment: oh my got you are right, kuh-chan. I'm blind :D

Comment: I have checked to make sure all persons have read and write access to folders.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error in the code. You can use the below code for image uploading.

```js
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();

      $dir = "images/";
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_name = $dir. $file_name;
      $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $tmp = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
      $file_ext=strtolower(end($tmp));
      
      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");
      
      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a GIF, JPEG or PNG file.";
      }
      
      if($file_size > 2097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }
      
      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>
      
      <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "image" />
         <input type = "submit"/>
      </form>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your code suggestion however when I try and run this code snippet it and test it locally it still does not upload anything.

Comment: If I run my code by directly From / by accessing the upload.php file this code works and the image is uploaded. However, I am trying to execute upload.php by including it in profile.php using php include. Not sure why this would make a difference.

Comment: Please check the folder path of the upload folder from "profile.php".
e.g. 
/var/www/html/profile.php
/var/www/html/incl/upload.php
/var/www/html/incl/images/

In above scenario, our path would be;
$dir = "incl/images/";
OR
$dir = "/var/www/html/incl/images/";

Hope this will work.